# the app didn't appear in my phone flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have flutter app,

I made some edit on the android side, and I added the native java code, and made some edit on manifest after the edit, flutter app didn't appear in my phone,

but the app appears in settings in apps

what is the problem ??

this is my Arduino manifest:

```
  <application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="flutter app"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
                 Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
                 screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
                 gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
                 Flutter's first frame. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <data android:scheme="com.jopoint" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />



              <!--  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>-->
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
        <service
            android:name="com.oppwa.mobile.connect.service.ConnectService"
            android:exported="false"/>
        <activity
            tools:replace="android:theme,android:windowSoftInputMode"
            android:name="com.oppwa.mobile.connect.checkout.dialog.CheckoutActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Checkout.Light"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
            android:exported="false"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

> what is the problem?

You commented out `android.intent.action.MAIN` action of your intent filter ([docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_MAIN)).

Comment: thank you, but I don't have a lot of information on android, how can I edit it to make my app appear?

Comment: just uncomment that line `<!--  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>-->` (which means removing `<!--` and `-->`

Comment: well, I remove it, but nothing change

Comment: EDIT: its working,,, i just move    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/> ..... after main activity

Comment: as your problem is solved, please mark the answer as accepted ([how to do that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86979/302464))